# How to remove the Unattached filter on Media Library List?

Tags: views

For example, at /wp-admin/upload.php are displayed the following filters by:

All (6) | Images (6) | Unattached (6)

How can I remove the "Unattached (6)" filter by?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, with the introduction of the `WP_List_Table` class, view filter are now hookable and specifically you can filter out that detached link like so..

```
add_filter( 'views_upload', 'upload_views_filterable' );
function upload_views_filterable( $views ) {
    unset( $views['detached']);
    return $views;
}
```

Bye bye detached link!... :)